# Answering "ambiguous" questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

For questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17411619/561731) where code works **perfectly** fine and there does not seem to be an issue, is is *ok* to answer the question with a *different* form of the question just because:

> The question is ambiguous... Waiting for more details from the OP, and then I will can update my answer.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411619/getjson-only-works-locally/17411672?noredirect=1#comment25284896_17411672)

?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184939/is-answering-a-question-with-your-problem-does-not-happen-in-an-isolated-enviro/184941#184941

Comment: your question is ambiguous - what answers do you want?

Comment: "I don't know what your question really is, so this is an answer to your question."

Answer (score 6):

No, you should not post such answers.  That's not an answer to the question; saying that you can't replicate their problem is just a comment.

You shouldn't be posting an answer at all if you feel that it needs to be updated based on later input from the OP to be a true answer.  You should feel, at the time you first post it, that it's an answer to the question.  If not, you shouldn't post it, you should post a comment until your clarifying questions are answered.

The question should also be closed with the offtopic sub-reason reason of:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and *include valid code to reproduce it*. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Since the problem can't be replicated with the information given.